# Wpf display another item to the grouping hearder

Tags: wpf, header, addition

A page displays different order number each contains multiple line items, need to total the amount and display it in the group header..please help with displaying  total amount for each order number.

The TotalAmount field is not getting displayed along with the Group header name which is the order number.

```
 <abcd:DetailsListView x:Name="EncumbranceEntriesList" Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentEncumbranceJournalEntries}"
            SelectionMode="Extended" ShowGroupItemCount="True" 
            IsSortingEnabled="False"
            ahtd:ListBoxExtensions.HasBindableSelectedItems="True">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:DetailsListViewStatePersistenceBehavior
                    ListViewState="{e:UISettingBinding EncumbranceJournalTabListViewState}"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommandIconStyle}"/>
                    </ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Refresh" InputGestureText="F5"
                        Command="{StaticResource RefreshCommand}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="{DynamicResource {local:ThemeResourceKey IconRefresh}}"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommandIconStyle}"/>
                                </ContextMenu.Resources>
                                <MenuItem Header="_Open Purchase Order" Command="{StaticResource OpenPOCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder}">
                                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                                        <Image Source="{DynamicResource {local:ThemeResourceKey IconOpen}}"/>
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <abcd:DetailsView>
                    <abcd:DetailsViewColumn Header="PO #" Width="140"
                        IsInitiallyVisible="False" IsUserHidable="False"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber}"
                        SortPropertyName="PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber"
                        GroupPropertyName="PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber"/>
                    <abcd:DetailsViewColumn Header="Line Item" Width="200"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PurchaseOrderDetail.ShortItemDescription}"/>
                    <abcd:DetailsViewColumn Header="Date" Width="80"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EntryDate, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}"
                        SortPropertyName="EntryDate" DefaultSortDirection="Descending"/>
                    <abcd:DetailsViewColumn Header="Encumbrance" Width="100"
                        SortPropertyName="Amount">
                        <abcd:DetailsViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding EncumbranceAmount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"
                                    TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </abcd:DetailsViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </abcd:DetailsViewColumn>
                    <abcd:DetailsViewColumn Header="Liquidation" Width="100"
                        SortPropertyName="Amount">
                        <abcd:DetailsViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LiquidationAmount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"
                                    TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </abcd:DetailsViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </abcd:DetailsViewColumn>                                       
                </abcd:DetailsView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                                        
                                            <TextBlock Text=" {Binding TotalAmount, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

        </abcd:DetailsListView>
    </Grid>
</etk:BusyIndicator>
```

Code behind is

```
private void AutoSortList()
    {
        ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EncumbranceEntriesList.ItemsSource);

        if (dataView != null && dataView.SortDescriptions.Count == 0)
        {
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PurchaseOrderDetail.TransactionDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("EntryDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            EncumbranceEntriesList.Group("PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrder.DisplayNumber");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a GroupStyle, you also have the HeaderTemplate which gives you "Name" & "ItemCount". Those correspond respectively to the name of the group and the number of items contained within it.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                            <Binding Path="ItemCount" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you, the name and the itemcount is already displaying...with the ShowGroupItemCount="True" ....what i need is to get the total amount of each line item in the group